# connect 2 different application in socket.io (REACT NATIVE)

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

Hi guys I am having trouble on getting the data from my `application a` to `application b`

so on my `application a`

```
useEffect(() => {
 setSocket(io('http://MY_SERVER_IP:3000', {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    jsonp:false,
    forceNew: true,
  }));
},[]);

const SendData = () => {
  socket.emit("user app info", dataInfo);
}
```

now on my `server` it's this

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("a user connected :D");
    //User info's
    socket.on("user app info", dataInfo => {
        // console.log(msg);
        io.emit("user app info", dataInfo);
    });
    //Driver info's
    socket.on("driver app info", msg => {
        io.emit("driver app info", msg);
    });
});
```

now I need to send it to my `application b`
here's how I do it but now working

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io('http://MY_SERVER_IP:3000', {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        jsonp: false,
        forceNew: true,
    }));
}, []);


const onAccept = (newOrder) => {
       socket.on("user app info", dataInfo => console.log(dataInfo));
}
```

but it won't show any logs at all . Can someone enlighten me please.  Thank you

Comment: I was facing the same issue so I switched to core WebSocket. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: @RajendranNadar so did you use react-native-websocket also??

Comment: No, I used native web API, there is not need for any package.

Comment: sorry but can you guide me a little bit on how to implement it on react native???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WebSocket API on React Native

### Step 1 -

Create ref for WSS connection

```
const ws = React.useRef(null)
```

### Step 2 -

Init websocket

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    ws.current = new WebSocket('URL to WS')

    ws.current.onopen = () => console.log('Connected')

    ws.current.onclose = () => console.log('Disconnected')

    return () => {
        ws.current.close()
    }
}, [])
```

### Step 3 -

Add the onMessage listener to receive incoming WS data.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!ws.current) return

    ws.current.onmessage = (val) => {
        const response = JSON.parse(val.data)

        console.log(response)
    }
}, [])
```

### To send some data use

```
ws.current.send(
    JSON.stringify({
       ...your payload data to server
    })
)
```

This is the minimal WSS connection code, rest is your way of handling the received data, and sending it to the server.

Comment: so i don't need any more imports right . does react native 0.60+ supports already a websocket connection|?

Comment: No imports, no packages, no libraries, tried & tested on RN above 0.60 up to RN 0.64